# Cordova plugins not working

Tags: android, cordova

*Edit for clarification:*
**The `<name>` you see in some of the files below is not actually part of the files, but it includes the company name which I had to censor.**

Test situation:

- Cordova 4
- OS X Yosemite
- Android 4.4 device (coupled with USB)
- Using Terminal; not Eclipse

What happens:
Using `cordova run --release` successfully builds and signs the .apk and the mobile device installs and opens it without issues. But, none of the plugins work. For example:

```
    title.on('click', function() {
        if (!navigator.camera) {
            alert('no camera!');
        } else {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(function success(data) {
            // do something
            }, function error(data) {});
        }
    });
```

Always alerts that there is no camera, which means Cordova did not add a `camera` object to the `window.navigator` object.

Below is some information about my cordova installation and some xml files, as far as I can tell nothing looks out of place. Note that it is not just the camera that does not work, I just used it as an example.

Cordova info:

```
Node version: v0.10.29

Cordova version: 4.0.1-nightly.2014.9.29

Config.xml file: 

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.<name>.App" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name><name> Mini</name>
    <description>
        De <name> app voor je telefoon
    </description>
    <author email="stephan@<name>.nl" href="https://<name>.nl">
        Het <name> Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
</widget>


Plugins: 

org.apache.cordova.camera,org.apache.cordova.dialogs,org.apache.cordova.file,org.apache.cordova.file-transfer,org.apache.cordova.media,org.apache.cordova.media-capture,org.apache.cordova.splashscreen,org.apache.cordova.vibration

Android platform:

Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 4
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86
```

cordova/config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.<name>.App" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name><name> Mini</name>
    <description>
        De <name> app voor je telefoon
    </description>
    <author email="stephan@<name>.nl" href="https://<name>.nl">
        Het <name> Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
</widget>
```

cordova/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
<

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.kaartje2go.App" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

cordova/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.<name>.App" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
    </feature>
    <name><name> Mini</name>
    <description>
        De <name> app voor je telefoon
    </description>
    <author email="stephan@<name>.nl" href="https://<name>.nl">
        Het <name> Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Checklist: Is your plugin loaded?

- Does your `index.html` load the `cordova.js` script? (i.e. if you have `www/index.html` then you can just reference `cordova.js`. This file is not in the `www` directory, but automatically generated by Cordova and inserted in your app)
- Is the plugin javascript loaded? Use Chrome or Safari to remote debug your android/iOS app.
- `cordova plugin ls`: Is your plugin listed?
- `plugins/android.json`: Is your plugin listed?
- Does `platforms/android/assets/www` have all files? (i.e. a `plugins` folder with scripts, `cordova_plugins.js` should mention your plugin, a platform-specific `cordova.js`)

Can you listen to the `deviceready` event to check if Cordova initializes at all? (If all scripts are in place)

Comment: This guy is a champ.

I saw a lot of older tutorials on Cordova and they were confusing as they're all different (Cordova seems to change structure quite a lot) and I figured `cordova.js` didn't need to be added anymore, as I could not find it. I assumed it would automatically be added during the build process. In the end, that was the thing. I added `cordova.js` to my `index.html` and everything works!

Comment: This helped me a lot. Was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this wasn't working!

Comment: I've `cordova plugin add <plugin>`s, but my `cordova plugin ls` returns emptly, and my plugins folder is emptly.  Any Idea why?

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I overlooked the inclusion of the cordova.js file. So many other cordova features seemed to working fine that I was misled into thinking there was something wrong with the camera plugin in particular.

Comment: How can I check if the plugin javascript is working? I don't get any errors on Chrome but on the iPhone Simulator the cordova camera plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If your plugins don't work you can also try these steps:

```
cordova plugin list;
cordova plugin remove my-cordova-plugin --save;
cordova plugin add my-cordova-plugin --nosave;
```

Also be aware of the following plugin dependencies:

1. The `file`, `file-transfer`, and `camera` plugins are all dependent on the `compat` plugin; so `compat` needs to be removed last.
2. The `file-transfer` plugin is dependent on `file`, so `file` needs to be removed first.

Answer (score 0):

Today I learned another cause why this can break: Ensure that your project does not have a second file named `cordova.js`, no matter where. If the cordova plugin management finds such a file included as  tag, it can wrongly assume that your own file’s base path is the base path of Cordova’s `cordova.js` and uses it as base path for loading its own JS files.