# facebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins

I'am using cordova with the plugin facebookconnect (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), but got this error : "ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined" when calling facebookConnectPlugin.login()

I've seen this error in a lot of threads, but nothing work.
The app is build on android for the moment.

There is some code I use, idk if you need more.

Cordova 5.0.0,
Java 1.7.0_71

### Config.xml (App):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.cordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description>
        Application mobile App.com
    </description>
    <author email="xxxxx" href="xxxxx">
        Name
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />

    <feature name="debug-server" required="false">
       <param name="domain" value="http://debug.custom.com"/>
       <param name="key" value="xxxxx"/>
    </feature>

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.11.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="App" />
    </gap:plugin>

    [...]
</widget>
```

---

### index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>App Mobile</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="facebook" onclick="return facebookConnect();">
        <span>Connect with Facebook</span>
    </p>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### In mobile.js:

```
function facebookConnect(){
    try {
        if (!('cordova' in window)){
            $.getScript('js/cordova.js');
        }
    } catch(error){
        alert(error);
    }

    try {
        $.getScript('js/facebookConnectPlugin.js');
    } catch(error){
        alert(error);
    }

    try {
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile', 'email'], function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) }, function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
    } catch(error){
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

---

Any help whould be much appreciated.

Comment: Curious as to why you are loading the cordova js file like this instead of : `$.getScript('js/cordova.js');`  Why not load cordova.js and facebookConnectPlugin.js like the other javascript files you are loading?  You must wait for the deviceready event to begin using plugins.  This stackoverflow answer provides a nice checklist to make sure you are ready to use your plugins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654231/cordova-plugins-not-working.

Comment: I'm not able to get the facbookConnectPlugin working. I keep getting the error "facebookConnectPlugin is not defined" on Android. I'm using phonegap build and have added my Android hash to facebook. Everything works fine on iOS, it's just that on Android I get that error. Were you able to get it working? If so, would you mind sharing how you got it to work?