# navigator.camera is undefined

Tags: android, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

This is the example from [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

I have also done this `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera` to add the plugin and changes for config.xml and android-manifest.xml with this

```
    <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`
 respectively.

my `android.json` file shows the camera plugin but still i was not able to access `camera`.

and one interesting thing is when i tried to remove plugin and reinstall i was not able to remove it was showing like `Error: Plugin "org.apache.cordova.camera" is not present in the project. See cordova plugin list`
but when i check the list it is present.

What heck happenning here i was trying all the different solutions from past 5hrs.

Comment: did u defined deviceready event listener and tried invoking the plugin inside the event listener?

Comment: @Gandhi same error navigator.camera is not defined on device ready also

Comment: have you included cordova.js file in your html?

Comment: @Gandhi  no i have not but i'm working in a team and the whole application is working fine. do you think that is the error. and i have also added geolocation plugin but i never added cordova.js in my html

Comment: @Gandhi i was trying to add it will be inside platforms right

Comment: it gets created automatically in the root folder (www) while building any platform like browser or android or ios. So you gotta include this file in any html where you are invoking plugin

Comment: @Gandhi i was really thankfull for your  solutions you made my day and one more thing is checkout this solution same as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654231/cordova-plugins-not-working

Comment: Glad that is helped. Have also posted the same in answers. You can accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others too. Happy Coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure to include cordova.js in your HTML file in order to invoke plugins from deviceready event listener.

Comment: fixed super (y)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/356

She have the same issue as you