# how to use cordova plugin in angular 4 hybrid application

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am new in this structure. I am added camera plugin into application and build the application. It throws below error.

*ERROR in D:/../CordovaApp/src/app/menu-bar/menu-bar.component.ts (20,15): Property 'camera' does not exist on type 'N
avigator'.


ERROR in D:/../CordovaApp/src/app/menu-bar/menu-bar.component.ts (23,16): Cannot find name 'Camera'.*

Can anyone help me to get rid out of this issue.

/** updated part **/
After adding two variable into component. Application build successfully but when I debug application I didn't get plugins property into navigator. Please refer below attached snap shot.

[click on this link to open snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5rrw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a typed language. So, whenever you use any javascript based library/plugin, you have to ensure the corresponding **type** is available.

Here, you have used navigator, which is actually known to JavaScript or Cordova, but not known to Typescript which causes this error.

> There are two ways to solve this.
>
> 1. Install corresponding type definition. (http://definitelytyped.org/)
> 2. Declaring navigator as **any** type.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<button type="button" (touchend)="onCamera($event)">Camera</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public onCamera(event) {
    const cameraOptions = {
      destinationType: (<any>Camera).DestinationType.FILE_URI
    };
    (<any>navigator).camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
  }
}
```

or

```
declare var navigator: any;
declare var Camera: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<button type="button" (touchend)="onCamera($event)">Camera</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public onCamera(event) {
    const cameraOptions = {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    };
    navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried above example but still i am facing same issue. ERROR : Cannot find name 'Camera'.
Any other suggestion.

Comment: Using the above code, you are getting the Error in Browser Console or Build Error? If you are getting error in browser console, then make sure if you have enabled Camera plugin in config.xml

Comment: Seems you are using Camera constants (Camera.destinationType.FILE_URI etc.) also. Can you declare Camera also like same.

declare var Camera: any; or (<any>Camera).destinationType.FILE_URI

I believe, it will solve your issue.

Comment: I got error while building angular app using 'ng build' command

Comment: I have modified the code above, see if that solves your issue.

Comment: using above solution application build successfully but when i trying to call navigator.camera plugin property it shows 'undefined'.

Comment: I added snap shot inside my question. i didn't found cordova plugin properties inside 'navigator' object.

Comment: Thank you Somnath..!! :) It was great help.
Above comment's issue has been solved.
using this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654680/5734133

Comment: I have the angular app separately from the cordova app. I build the angular app, and the result code is written to the cordova app folder. So even if I add the type definitions to the angular project, I won't have this working, because only the cordova app has the plugins. I think that may be this answer doesn't take into account the possibility for such separate architecture. I don't know how to proceed now. I have to think of solution how to test this thing without the cordova code.

Comment: @makkasi did you tried with the above sample? The above samples are just to inform typescript to transpile the code with declared type and it does not require any connection with source code.